# Reading Excel file with spaces in the cells

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to read some spaces that are present in the excel file. Below is the format of the Excel file.

```
   Col1         Col2   Col3
   12345               11        
   34568         9     12
   87654        10     13
```

I have above in once cell of the excel worksheet. When I start reading 12345, 34568.. they are all terminated by line feed.
When I start reading Col2, I can read 9 and 10, but I don't see any space before 9 and 10. Although, I can see the visible space in Col2, but it is not coming while reading the excel spreadsheet. I also tried testing the space with this function

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dr(0),5)
{
   int j = i - 4;
   rowArray[j]= dr(0,5).Text.ToString();
}
```

I read the whole spreadsheet in a datatable and that might be omitting the spaces.

Is there any way that I can read that space above 9.

Below is the code to read the excel file

```
 public void getExcelFile()
    {
         Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
         Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\ExcelFiles\msl.xls");
         Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
         Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
         int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
         string x;
         string p;
         int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

         for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
             {
                 //new line
                 if (j == 1)
                     Console.Write("\r\n");

                 //write the value to the console
                 if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                 {
                     x = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t";

                    Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");
                 }

             }
         }

         Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
         Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

         //close and release
         xlWorkbook.Close();
         Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);


    }
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: within your code of reading this into a datatable can you show that..

Comment: I added the code above. Unfortunately, its in VB.net